# Move directories using wildcards

Tags: command-line, move

I have a series of folders that I need to move around that are organized as such:

- Parent

  - ABC1
  - ABC2
  - DEF1
  - DEF2
  - ...
  - XYZ1
  - XYZ2

I would like to move all of the sub directories and their contents that end in "1" into a new folder (block1) and do the same ending in "2." I would assume it would involve some sort of for loop and wildcards "???1", but I'm having trouble finding a solutions.

EDIT**

Another question, just to make things more difficult. Suppose that I have within each folder a specific set of files I'd like to move:

- Parent

  - ABC1

    - ABC_cath1_001
    - ABC_cath1_002
    - ABC_cath2_001
    - ABC_cath2_002

And I'd like to only move ABC_cath1* files into the new folder - is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
 md temp 
 for /f %a in ('dir /b *1') do move %a temp\%a
 ren temp block1


 md temp 
 for /f %a in ('dir /b *2') do move %a temp\%a
 ren temp block2
```

Comment: AHHHH!!! Yesssss, thank you so much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the things listed here are folders

```
move C:\parent\???1 C:\block1 

move C:\parent\???2 C:\block2
```

If your Job is just to move these folders these commands will work ,I dont think so that you need to write a batch script with loops

Comment: Tried that before, won't work. It will list it if I just do  

dir C:parent\???1  

But it won't execute the move command

Comment: Okay @Devin Let me tell you how I tested please correct me if your scenario is different , I created 4 files called ABC1 ABC2 ABC3 and tried move C:\parent\???1 C:\block1